# Creating a football data visualization in Processing?

Tags: processing, data-visualization

I was wondering if anyone knows where I can get this kind of data to work on a data visualization of it. I'm looking to take quite a few countries from around the world and map the number of times they have won the world cup over a hundred years. Is there anywhere I can get the data from for this? In terms of mapping it on my data visualization, where should I start? I'm using Processing.

Comment: This question is not really right on Stack Overflow. But take a look at Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Cup. There's a list of all the winners, results, host countries and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Ben Fry, one of the creators of Processing, has written a good book on the topic data visualization. This will not only provide you with code and tools for making your application, but also more information about data visualization in general as well as inspiration

[Ben Fry: Visualizing Data](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596514557)

For data, if you want to look into a specific field I would recommend you to find an API which provides you with structured data about it, but your visualiation will not contain too many rows (in the magnitude of less than 100?) and can probably be hand-coded or screengrabbed from Homayoun Afshari's link.

[OpenFooty API for football data](http://www.footytube.com/openfooty/)

Answer (score 0):

data: [FIFA World Cup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Cup)

visualization : [jvectormap](http://jvectormap.com/)